# Opencart VQMod template issue

Tags: xml, opencart, admin

I want to remove the following tabs: attribute, option, discount, special, reward points, design from the Admin section of Catalog >  Products > Add New.

I'm using the following in the VQMod .xml file but the tab attribute continues to display. Any ideas what I have done wrong, or how to remove these tabs?

```
    <file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            <a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            <a href="#tab-attribute" style='display:none'><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

I'm using Opencart 1.5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[tab-attribute"]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[tab-attribute" style="display: none"]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Note that this will hide both the tab item and the actual tab content from view (or should - untested). If this doesn't work and the tab still shows, you may need to use a HTML commenting replacement to remove the tab item as it may be the jQuery code creating tabs that overrides the `display: none`

Comment: Ok i've tried as shown above, with no success. There wasn't speech marks missing in the code you provided by any chance? Notice there is two closing ones but no opening one.

Comment: Hi Lee. No there wasn't anything missing. What version of vQmod are you using and have you renamed your admin folder?

Comment: Hi there, no I haven't renamed the Admin folder, as have other xml VQMod files working on the admin section. The version is shown as this in the vqmod_opencart.xml file: <version>1.4.x and 1.5.x</version>

Comment: That's not the vQmod version - open the `/vqmod/vqmod.php` file and search for vqversion and there will be a number next to it. Clear all of the contents of the `/vqmod/vqcache/` folder and then refresh the page. If it still doesn't work, check that firstly the /vqmod/vqcache/ folder has files in it after the refresh and then check the error log file to see if there are any errors in there

Comment: 2.1.7 is the version, sorry about that, relatively new to this VQmod. And I need to delete all files in the vqcache folder? This won't affect it from working?

Comment: Anyway I went ahead and deleted them, refreshed the page and the attribute tabs is still there. I checked the vqcache folder and there were again files in there. Checked the log and there appears to be no errors generated by the vqmod file.

Comment: Resolved this now, thanks for the help, will post answer when it allows me.

Comment: @LeeBrown glad you got it sorted, would be interested to see the resolution to this

Comment: @LeeBrown Hi, how did you resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide reward points from the left-coloumn main menu in open cart-2.0.1.0 . For that do the following:

opencart-2.0.1.0---->upload---->catalog---->view---->theme---->default---->template---->module---->account.tpl

search for the line:

```
<a href="<?php echo $reward; ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $text_reward; ?></a>
```

and comment it like this:

```
<!-- <a href="<?php echo $reward; ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $text_reward; ?></a> -->
```

now refresh your page and check ,you can see that the reward point option is gone!